# Java: Program stdout and stderr to some sort of handler

Tags: java, stdout, handler, stderr

Is there a way to capture the stdout and stderror of my Java program line by line?

Perhaps something similar to the way you can add a handler to a Logger instance using `addHandler`.

**edit:** I don't want to replace the default handlers--I still need the output to show up on the command line.

Comment: What is the reason for the requirement?  If it's for logging or debugging you should consider using a logging framework rather than stderr and stdout. If you're on a *nix system you can just redirect the stdout and stderr to a file and tail the file...

Comment: I am writing a streaming API where you can get the console output for the program. So whatever goes into the console can also be viewed as a http stream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using [System.setOut()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29) and [System.setErr()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setErr%28java.io.PrintStream%29) you can set standard output and error stream to any PrintStream, and capture everything.

**ADDITION:**
I don't know if there exist any elegant way to do this, but one way to do so is:
1. Save default output stream
    PrintStream defaultOut  = System.out;
(System.getOut() would be fun to have though)
2. Redirect System.out to the printstream you want (e.g. any file)
3. Instead of using System.out.println() use your print function, which does following:
    print(Object o){
    defaultOut.println(o);//Assuming that defaultOut is visible in this function
    System.out.println(o);
    }

Comment: I don't want to replace the PrintStreams because I still need the output to go to the command line.

Answer (score 2):

The methods `System.setOut` and `System.setErr` allow you to change the `PrintStream` objects that the `System.out` and `System.err` variables refer to.   You can use them to replace the default `PrintStream` objects with objects that capture output, or do whatever you want with it.

**FOLLOWUP**

> I don't want to replace the PrintStreams because I still need the output to go to the command line.

Your code can take care of that:

1. Create a subclass of `OutputStream` that writes all output to another `OutputStream` instance, and also captures the output.  Make the "other" instance a constructort parameter.
2. Get the current values of `System.out` and `System.err`.
3. Instantiate your subclass twice, with the `System.out` and `System.err` values as constructor parameters respectively.
4. Wrap those two instances as `PrintStream` instances.
5. Call `System.setOut` and `System.setErr` to replace `System.out` and `System.err` with the `PrintStream` instances.

Comment: Keep in mind that this will redirect the System.out and System.err streams, but will *not* redirect anything that the JVM prints out directly, such as when you do a "kill -3" on it to dump the thread and lock information.

Comment: I don't want to replace the PrintStreams because I still need the output to go to the command line.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin - that's true.  Unfortunately, there's nothing you can do about that short of hacking the JVM codebase, or launching the JVM from another JVM.

Comment: Interesting. The way I implemented it was by extending `ByteArrayOutputStream`, overriding flush and then using `new PrintStream(new HandleStdOut())`. Is there any difference?

Answer (score 1):

The [Message Console](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/) allows you to display output in a text pane and display it on the command line.